# No puedo terminar de instalar snapd en CentOS

Tags: centos

He intentado instalar snap siguiendo estas instrucciones: [link](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-centos).

Primer paso: yum install snapd , todo correcto, me sale un mensaje indicando que fue exitoso.

Segundo paso: systemctl enable --now snapd.socket

Allí recibo el siguiente mensaje:

```
> systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Soy novato en Linux. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme a saber qué puedo haber hecho mal o qué sucede? Paso toda la información que necesiten.

El SO es CentOS Linux 7.9.2009

EDITADO: Soy usuario root. De todas maneras, ya probé haciendo ambos pasos con sudo y pasa lo mismo: instala correctamente y luego devuelve el mismo mensaje.

Comment: Y si intentas con sudo como indican las instrucciones que enlazas en tu pregunta? Puede ser problema de permisos...

Comment: Perdón, debí aclarar que soy usuario root pero que de todas formas también probé con sudo. Ya modifico la pregunta para agregarlo > sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Significa que tienes que mostrar claramente que sí instalaste correctamente. Tu escenario no se replica.

Si yo replico tu escenario, al hacer `yum install epel-release` y luego `yum install snapd` la salida es:

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa centos-release
centos-release-7-9.2009.1.el7.centos.x86_64

[root@localhost ~]# yum install epel-release

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package epel-release.noarch 0:7-11 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                 Arch                                              Version                                          Repository                                         Size
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 epel-release                                            noarch                                            7-11                                             extras                                             15 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 15 k
Installed size: 24 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                                                 |  15 kB  00:00:00     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : epel-release-7-11.noarch                                                                                                                                                                         1/1 
  Verifying  : epel-release-7-11.noarch                                                                                                                                                                         1/1 

Installed:
  epel-release.noarch 0:7-11                                                                                                                                                                                        

Complete!
[root@localhost ~]# yum install snapd
Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                    Arch                                       Version                                                       Repository                                Size
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 snapd                                                      x86_64                                     2.58.3-1.el7                                                  epel                                      17 M
Installing for dependencies:
 audit-libs-python                                          x86_64                                     2.8.5-4.el7                                                   base                                      76 k
 bash-completion                                            noarch                                     1:2.1-8.el7                                                   base                                      87 k
 checkpolicy                                                x86_64                                     2.5-8.el7                                                     base                                     295 k
 fuse                                                       x86_64                                     2.9.2-11.el7                                                  base                                      86 k
 fuse-libs                                                  x86_64                                     2.9.2-11.el7                                                  base                                      93 k
 libcgroup                                                  x86_64                                     0.41-21.el7                                                   base                                      66 k
 libsemanage-python                                         x86_64                                     2.5-14.el7                                                    base                                     113 k
 libzstd                                                    x86_64                                     1.5.5-1.el7                                                   epel                                     292 k
 policycoreutils-python                                     x86_64                                     2.5-34.el7                                                    base                                     457 k
 python-IPy                                                 noarch                                     0.75-6.el7                                                    base                                      32 k
 setools-libs                                               x86_64                                     3.3.8-4.el7                                                   base                                     620 k
 snap-confine                                               x86_64                                     2.58.3-1.el7                                                  epel                                     3.5 M
 snapd-selinux                                              noarch                                     2.58.3-1.el7                                                  epel                                     550 k
 squashfs-tools                                             x86_64                                     4.3-0.21.gitaae0aff4.el7                                      base                                     101 k
 squashfuse                                                 x86_64                                     0.1.102-1.el7                                                 epel                                      18 k
 squashfuse-libs                                            x86_64                                     0.1.102-1.el7                                                 epel                                      24 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+16 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 23 M
Installed size: 62 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y

Installed:
  snapd.x86_64 0:2.58.3-1.el7                                                                                                                                                                                       

Dependency Installed:
  audit-libs-python.x86_64 0:2.8.5-4.el7   bash-completion.noarch 1:2.1-8.el7       checkpolicy.x86_64 0:2.5-8.el7        fuse.x86_64 0:2.9.2-11.el7                         fuse-libs.x86_64 0:2.9.2-11.el7    
  libcgroup.x86_64 0:0.41-21.el7           libsemanage-python.x86_64 0:2.5-14.el7   libzstd.x86_64 0:1.5.5-1.el7          policycoreutils-python.x86_64 0:2.5-34.el7         python-IPy.noarch 0:0.75-6.el7     
  setools-libs.x86_64 0:3.3.8-4.el7        snap-confine.x86_64 0:2.58.3-1.el7       snapd-selinux.noarch 0:2.58.3-1.el7   squashfs-tools.x86_64 0:4.3-0.21.gitaae0aff4.el7   squashfuse.x86_64 0:0.1.102-1.el7  
  squashfuse-libs.x86_64 0:0.1.102-1.el7  

Complete!
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/snapd.socket to /usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket.
```